# What is the "WriteMessage API" / recommended way to serialize a message with ProtoWriter.State?

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm using the ProtoReader/ProtorWriter.State API to manually read/write messages, because the format of messages is user-defined at runtime and we want to avoid using reflection to generate TypeModels.

I have a working example in which I use a custom `ISerializer` to write nested messages with the `ProtoWriter.State.WriteMessage` method. I'd like to drop the serializer and just write the nested message directly (since the serializer doesn't provide any benefit in this scenario).

This seems to be a simple exercise of calling:

```cs
var token = state.StartSubItem(null, style);
// actual write methods, contents of my ISerializer.Write() method
state.EndSubItem(token, style);
```

However, the Start/EndSubItem methods are deprecated and state:

> If possible, please use the WriteMessage API; this API may not work correctly with all writers

For the life of me, I can't find any information about this WriteMessage API in the repo or the source; all `WriteMessage` methods seems to end up using the deprecated Start/EndSubItem methods (or throw exceptions with similar warnings to use the WriteMessage API).

**Anyone know where I can find (information about) this WriteMessage API?**
Or recommendations / examples on how to serialize (sub-)messages in general.

Or does this simply mean that I should manually implement what the Start/EndSubItem methods do, which (aside from various checks) is apparently just to write the message length?